# How to edit all fields in a Microsoft Dataverse record using Power Apps GUI

Tags: powerapps, dataverse

Within a Power Apps environment, a table has been created with some custom columns as well. Then data has been created and added to the table within the Power Apps GUI. When adding a record, only the `Primary name column` is available for data entry.

After choosing the `Table`, then choosing the `Data` tab, and then `Edit Record`, only the `Primary name column` is available to edit. Other columns have been defined but are not presented on the new or edit record screens.

Is it possible to edit all fields in a Dataverse record using the Power Apps GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the custom fields to a custom `form`. Use that form to edit the data.